# WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, google-colaboratory

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmND8.png) getting error on running code in colab

WebDriverException

Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 driver = webdriver.Chrome()

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in       check_response(self, response)
227                 alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
228             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type:    ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 229         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location  /root/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/116.0.5845.96/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.